# Firebase token refresh

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, token

Firebase documentation clearly states that `FirebaseInstanceIdService` should be implemented to access refreshed token and that manual registration is not required anymore, since the library cares for all the process.

Problem is that `onTokenRefresh` is only called once, and if something goes wrong in the process of transferring it to my server, application has to wait until next refresh or do a complete uninstall/reinstall.

Could I apply the same logic as previous GCM implementations? That is, on every start of my application I access token using `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` and sent it to my server, not caring if it has already been sent. Same thing is done in `onTokenRefresh`.

Does this approach have any pitfall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I suggest that at first time when you get TOKEN stored it locally (may be in shared pref) and

> make one flag initialize it as a false

and then try to send TOKEN to your server it sent successfully turn flag ti true, and no need to send again.

Answer (score 12):

Also, it seems you can call this function from outside of the service

`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();`